.htaccess rule to implement root and subfolder in same way
we have a directory in which there is a index.php file, for which we have defined rule via .htaccess which is working fine, now we need to create a subdirectoy that will also have index.php file.
Now we want, the rules we have implemented for rootDir/index.php should also work for the subdirectory if the name of the subdirectory is in the path like - rootDir/Subdirectory/index.php, and if there is no subdirectory name in the path it should work for root directory file.
Here is the current htaccess code  -
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

current location of .htaccess file is -  rootDir/.htaccess
Please share your suggestion to solve it.

Copy the file also to the subfolder.

Okay, but how will the system identify, is this call for rootDir or to subfolder?

The system does not know, but the apache2 webservice. You still have all the query data.

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?[^/]+/?$ $1index.php [L]

Last rule will present index.php file from the subdirectory in the request path.
